# DelphiWin32 - Generate an object of a specific class

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am using Delphi 2009. I have a TListBox with several items. I want to generate an object of specific class for each item selected. So if user select the item number 2 and click Create button an object of specific class is created. I was thinking to implement it just checking the index value of current item selected and then use if-then-else. Or should I use class reference i.e. for each click on item I set the type of class reference and then I create the object in OnClick event of button? I would like to avoid all these controls and just create the object basing on the value of item string. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

There are several options.

**Simple Index**

The simple solution is:

```
case ListBox1.ItemIndex of
  0 : temp := TApple.Create;
  1 : temp := TPineapple.Create;
  2 : temp := TGrape.Create;
else
  raise EFruitError.Create('Unknown fruit');
end;
```

Its clear, but you have to maintain the list at two places, which can lead to errors.

**Class references**

Assume all fruit descend from TFruit with a virtual constructor. Then you can do:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(const Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.AddObject('Apple', TApple);
  ListBox1.AddObject('Pineapple', TPineapple);
  ListBox1.AddObject('Grape', TGrape);
end;

// Event handler:
procedure TForm1.CreateButtonClick(const Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex>=0 then
    temp := TFruit(ListBox1.Items.Objects[ListBox1.ItemIndex]).Create;
end;
```

This has a single point of maintenance. Which is great.

**Reference based on name**
But if you want to create the objects based on a name in the list, you can create some kind of factory:

```
type
  TFruitClass = class of TFruit;
  TFruitFactory = class
  public
    class function CreateFruit(const AName: string): TFruit;
    class procedure RegisterFruit(const AName: string; const AFruitClass: TFruitClass);
  end;
```

The factory is used to bind classes to names. Each class is registered using a name. And now you just give the name to the factory and the factory returns the required class.

Comment: For the registration part, you can use a TClassList defined in Contnrs.pas to maintain a list of TFruit classes.  The listbox change handler would loop through the class types in this list to find the one that corresponds to the item selected.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Gamecat's answer, you can use class utility functions in 'classes.pas'. Below sample uses the [`GetClass`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_GetClass.html) function (and assumes objects to be created descend from TControl):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.CommaText := 'TEdit,TButton,TPanel';
  RegisterClasses([TButton, TEdit, TPanel]);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pc: TPersistentClass;
  c: TControl;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex > -1 then begin
    pc := GetClass(ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
    if Assigned(pc) then begin
      c := TControlClass(pc).Create(Self);
      c.Parent := Self;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: With regards to class reference the line:

Comment: ListBox1.AddObject('Apple', TApple);
it should be ListBox1.Items.AddObject('Apple', TApple); I assume TApple is class reference but if I define it as TApple = class of TMyClass then I got type not compatibile TObject and class reference :-((

Comment: @user - I think you meant to post this comment to Gamecat's answer, he'll not be aware of these comments until you repost them under his answer.

Comment: If I may help in the meantime; do not add reference to a class to the object list, use it to create an instance. While adding a class type to 'Items.Objects' cast it to a 'TObject'. I.e. if `TApple = classs(TFruit)` then use `ListBox1.Items.AddObject('Apple', TObject(TApple))`. You'll still get an AV if you try to create an instance on a class, you need to change it: if `TFruitClass = class of TFruit` and `temp: TFruit` then `    temp := TFruitClass(ListBox1.Items.Objects[ListBox1.ItemIndex]).Create`